# Отчество от имени Наиль

Tags: ономастика

Как правильно будет звучать отчество: Наильевна или Наилевна?

Answer (score 3):

Вы имеете в виду отчество *Вашей дочери*?
***Наилевна***, сына - ***Наилевич***.
Известна так же фамилия Наилев.

"Наильевич, Наильевна" было бы от гипотетического имени "*Наилий", но такое не фиксируется.

Comment: Спасибо! Остановились на отчества Наилевна

Answer (score 1):

В сети широко встречаются оба варианта : Наилевна и Наильевна. Я думаю, вариант окончания отчества зависит от выбора родителей. Предпочтение оказывается той форме, которая гармонирует с именем ребенка и нравится его родным.

Comment: Два известных спортсмена : хоккеист Сергей Наильевич Гимаев и футболист Марат Наилевич Измайлов.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?sclient=tablet-gws&newwindow=1&hl=ru-RU&source=android-browser&q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&oq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&gs_l=tablet-gws.3..0j0i10i30j0i5i30.33891.35921.0.37254.11.6.0.0.0.0.399.632.2-1j1.2.0....0...1c..64.tablet-gws..10.1.232.Wrwxr5KPD3Q Фамилия Наильев

Comment: Марселевич/Марсельевич.

Comment: Отчество Фидельевич.

Comment: Отчество Вильевич. Имя отца - Виль  (от инициалов В.И.Ленина).

Comment: Отчества Польевич и Жан-Польевич.

Comment: На десерт - отчество Жюльевич.

Answer (score 1):

У меня отец Наиль. Меня записали как Наталью Наиловну, но мне было бы приятнее Наильевна, тем более, что получилось бы редкое ГиЛЬманова НатаЛЬя НаиЛЬевна...

Comment: а куда девается мягкий знак?)Наиль-Наильевич-Наильевна...Разве не так?)

Comment: а зачем вам мягкий знак перед смягчаюшим гласным? "Наильевич" читается как [наиль-йевич] - тут йот совершенно лишний. А "Наилевич" - так и читается с мягким Л. Какие-то знаки не нужны. Сравните: "кошель-кошелёк", "метель-метелица", "учитель-учителя" - Никаких знаков не требуется. Путаница возникает из-за наличия двух близких вариантов имени. "Василь"(южнославянский вариант)-"Василий". Вот "Наилович" - это да, нарушение фонетики в любом случае.

Answer (score 1):

> "Наильевич, Наильевна" было бы от гипотетического имени "*Наилий", но
>   такое не фиксируется.

Наилий-Наилиевич...Или я ошибаюсь?)

Comment: Если и ошибаетесь, то по мелочи. В современных реалиях такие отчества имеют форму с мягким знаком нужен. Виталий-Витал**ь**евич. Геннадий-Геннад**ь**евчич. Наилий - Наил**ь**евич. Полногласные варианты  "Геннадиевчич", "Виталиевич" и т. д. рассматриваются как альтернативные формы и гораздо менее употребительны.  Но что безусловно верно, так это то, что не "Наилевич".